# VueJS Vuex - Promise that resolves on state change?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, promise, vuejs2, vuex

Is it possible to create a Promise that resolves once a variable in the global vuex store changes?

I have a variable that is initialized as `null` in the state store and will be populated via an asynchronous call.
A different part of the app is dependent on that variable being `true` or `false` and is supposed to wait while it is still `null`.

Is there a way to cleanly wait for the change of this variable?

Comment: Who makes the asynchronous call? Can't you just immediately populate the variable with the promise?

Comment: You mean put the promise itself in the global store? I haven't tried that yet but even if it would work, it doesn't quite feel right to me... Shouldn't the global state be in a defined state? I'd prefer to create a promise outside of it à la `while(state.foo == undefined) { wait(100); } resolve(state.foo)` but I don't know if that's possible and how to make that work...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can [`vm.$watch`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-watch) on an expression or function and then [wrap that with a promise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22519784/how-do-i-convert-an-existing-callback-api-to-promises).

```
function watch(vm, fn) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    const watcher = vm.$watch(fn, (newVal) => {
      resolve(newVal);
      watcher(); // cleanup;
    });
  });
}
```

This would let you do something like:

```
let change = await watch(vm, () => state.foo); // will resolve when state.foo changes
```

Inside an `async function`.

Note in general this isn't a terrific pattern and in most cases it is preferable and simpler to use a [computed property](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#computed) (and not a promise) for this.

Comment: I ended up simply polling as described in the answer to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30505960/use-promise-to-wait-until-polled-condition-is-satisfied
But your solution does look interesting, I'll keep that in mind for next time!

Comment: @TommyF please be careful doing that for multiple values since it bypasses Vue's own reactivity system which is built for listening for changes.

Comment: I understand, and I'm only using it outside of an actual vue component. But thanks for the warning.

Comment: To be clear, I acknowledge there are cases where doing it with polling might be appropriate and easier. For example because even if you refactor vue out it'll continue to work.

Comment: You can also do exactly the same with Vuex watch. Just store instead of vm to watch and change vm.$watch with vm.watch.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to Benjamin's answer and not exactly what you are asking for, just another option. Instead of watching state change you can [subscribe](https://vuex.vuejs.org/api/#subscribe) to when a mutation of a specific type occurs and wrap that into a Promise.

```
new Promise(resolve => {
      let unsubscribeFn = this.$store.subscribe(mutation => {
        if (mutation.type === "MY_MUTATION") {
          unsubscribeFn();
          resolve();
        }
      });
    });
```