# console.log doesn't return result in async after await

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a code that waits till file exist and returns file content. I run code, it waits for 'smscode.txt' file. After I upload 'smscode.txt' code finishes execution. That's correct.

But for some reason console.log(2); doesn't display anything.
Here is the result of my function execution.

```
c:\work\docker\test-npm>node ideaOpen.js
1

c:\work\docker\test-npm>
```

**Updated and simplified code version, without files**

I expect "2" to be displayed, but it does not. In 5 seconds script successfully finishes its work.

```js
let smsCode = '';
function checkSmsCode() {
    setTimeout(function(){
        smsCode = 1234;
    }, 5000);
}
checkSmsCode();

let smsCodeExist = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (smsCode) {
        resolve(smsCode);
    }
});

(async () => {
    console.log(1);
    let a = await smsCodeExist;
    console.log(2);
})();
```

Comment: I would try using `then` instead of `await`. Something like: `smsCodeExist.then((response)=> console.log(2))`. I this case function doesn't have to be asynchronous.

Comment: if you're using setTimeout to wait for asynchronous result, you don't know how promises work

Comment: `checkSmsCode` is asynchronous, but you don't use promises in it.

Comment: You have a race condition. What happens when `setTimeout` in `smsCodeExist` runs before `smsCode` is set? In fact it will never work unless the first `checkSmsCode()` call succeeds (which I assume it never does).

Comment: There is a lot wrong in that code. Not sure why you are not just using await around the file reading which would eliminate all the extra code.

Comment: The use of the [file watcher API](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/fs.html#fs_class_fs_fswatcher) might be appropriate here too to avoid race conditions and/or explicit polling of values...

Comment: @epascarello File may not exist. I want to wait till file appears

Comment: but how you coded it makes no sense and it will not wait around until it exists....

Comment: @epascarello probably, my code is not good, I'm new to JS Promises and async/await functionality. But it works.. It really waits till file appears and only after this script stops execution. You may test. I'm trying to rework code right now, but still thinking about the best way.

Comment: @Bravo I removed setTimeout from promised and emulated SmsCode cahnge with a delay. See updated question. Why code still not working?

Comment: @Barmar I removed setTimeout from promised and emulated SmsCode cahnge with a delay. See updated question. Why code still not working?

Comment: `if (smsCode) {` runs too early. For this code to make any sense at all, it needs to be ran *after* the setTimeout has completed.

Comment: @KevinB Example is simplified. I can't control smsCode variable change. For example, it can change as a result of AJAX call somewhere outside instead of timeout.

Comment: that's fine, but the fact remains. It must occur after. How you make that happen is irrelevant.

Comment: then there are no difference with usual function in my example. There are no need in Promise then.

Answer (score 0):

With a help of this stackoverflow question, I was able to find a solution.
[Use Promise to wait until polled condition is satisfied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30505960/use-promise-to-wait-until-polled-condition-is-satisfied)

```js
let smsCode = '';
function checkSmsCode() {
    setTimeout(function(){
        smsCode = 1234;
    }, 5000);
}
checkSmsCode();

let smsCodeExist = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    waitForSmsCode(resolve);
});


function waitForSmsCode(resolve) {
    if (!smsCode) {
        setTimeout(waitForSmsCode.bind(this, resolve), 500);
    } else {
        resolve(smsCode);
    }
}

(async () => {
    console.log(1);
    let a = await smsCodeExist;
    console.log(2);
    console.log(a);
})();
```

P.S.
Answer for original question with file read (script waits till file exist)

```
    var fs = require('fs');
    let smsCode = '';

    function waitForSmsCode(resolve) {
        fs.readFile('smscode.txt', 'utf8', (err, contents) => {
            smsCode = contents;
        });
        if (!smsCode) {
            setTimeout(waitForSmsCode.bind(this, resolve), 500);
        } else {
            resolve(smsCode);
        }
    }

    let smsCodeExist = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        waitForSmsCode(resolve);
    });

    (async () => {
        console.log(1);
        let smsCode = await smsCodeExist;
        console.log(smsCode);
    })();
```